# In next.js, swipe's auto slide function doesn't work. I'm not sure what's wrong

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I added a function so that the slide function automatically advances, but that function did not work.

```
<Swiper
  spaceBetween={180}
  slidesPerView={1}
  //navigation
  pagination={{ clickable: true }}
  //scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
  loop="true" 
  autoplay={{
    delay: 2000,
    disableOnInteraction: false, 
  }}
  effect="fade"
  speed={1000}
  style={{
    width: "93%",
  }}
>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.